# How can I create a LAN with controlled Internet access?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, lan

I'm designing a photo printing station, which is going to be installed in a public place. This station has a PC with Win7, and must have an internet connection for monitoring purposes.

Ir order for users to upload their photos, from their mobile phones to the machine, they must connect their phones via Wifi to a LAN provided by a router (TP Link TL-MR3020).

The uploading and printing processes work just fine, as long as the PC and the mobile phone share the same LAN. However, I have a little problem: I haven't been able to disable internet access for users, while keeping their LAN connection via Wifi.

In summary, I need the following:

- One PC connected to a LAN (via cable or Wifi) with Internet access.
- Different mobile phones connected to the same LAN via Wifi, without Internet access.

How can I achieve this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd put a router/packet filter between the LAN and the internet (or the net that lies upstream). Let that only pass connections from the PC into the internet not from any other devices (and possibly the other way, if the PC should be accessible from the internet).

Or have another NIC, into another network, in the PC solely for the purpose of internet access. Make sure the PC doesn't route (which should be the default case with Windows 7).

Comment: Finally I set up two routers, one for Internet connection and another for the LAN. Works perfectly, thank you.